# Script hangs while using Fabric's Connection.run() in the background

Tags: python, linux, fabric, freeze

### Overview

I'm trying to use python fabric to run an ssh command as root on a remote server.

The command: `nohup ./foo &`

`foo` is expected to command run for several days.  I must be able to disassociate `foo` from fabric's remote ssh session, and put `foo` in the background.

The [Fabric FAQ](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html) says you should use something like `screen` or `tmux` when you run your fabric script (which runs the backgrounded command).  I tried that, but my fabric script still hung.  `foo` is not hanging.

### Question

How do I use fabric to run this command on a remote server without the script hanging: `nohup ./foo &`

### Details

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20895/6766
if "true" : '''\'
    then
    exec "/nfs/it/network_python/$OSREL/bin/python" "$0" "$@"
    exit 127
fi
'''

from getpass import getpass
import os

from fabric import Connection, Config

assert os.geteuid()==0, "ERROR: Must run as root"

for host in ['host1.foo.local', 'host2.foo.local']:
    # Make an ssh connection to the host...
    conn = Connection(host)

    # The script always hangs at this line 
    result = conn.run('nohup ./foo &', warn=True, hide=True)
```

I always open a `tmux` session to run the aforementioned script in; even doing so, the script hangs when I get to `conn.run()`, above.

I'm running the script on a vanilla CentOS 6.5 VM; it runs under python 2.7.10 and fabric 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fabric FAQ is unclear... I thought the FAQ wanted `tmux` used on the local side when I executed the Fabric script.

The correct way to fix this problem is to replace `nohup` in the remote command, with `screen -d -m <command>`.  Now I can run the whole script locally with no hangs (and I don't have to use `tmux` in the local term).

Explicitly, I have to rewrite the last line of my script in my question as:

```
    # Remove &, and nohup...
    result = conn.run('screen -d -m ./foo', warn=True, hide=True)
```